# silverlight Binding from VM collection to View not working need some help

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I know I am missing something here and I could use a pointer. Within a project I have an expander control when this control is clicked it makes a RIA call to a POCO within my project to retreive a second set of data. I am using the SimpleMVVM toolkit here so please let me know if I need to expand on any additional areas.

Within the xaml the expander is laid out as

```
<toolkit:Expander  Header="Name"  Style="{StaticResource DetailExpanderSytle}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction
                                TargetObject="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}}"
                                MethodName="showWarrantNameDetail"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding NameResult}" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="200">

                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                        <local:NameContainer DataContext="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </toolkit:Expander>
```

I am using the expression Dll coupled with Simple MVVM to get at the methods in the view model vs commands. 
Within the view model I have the following code

```
        public void showWarrantNameDetail()
    {
        //set flags
        IsBusy = true;
        CanDo = false;
        EntityQuery<WarrantNameDataView> query = App.cdContext.GetWarrantNameDataViewsQuery().Where(a => a.PrimaryObjectId == Convert.ToInt32(RecID));
        Action<LoadOperation<WarrantNameDataView>> completeProcessing = delegate(LoadOperation<WarrantNameDataView> loadOp)
        {
            if (!loadOp.HasError)
            {
                processWarrantNames(loadOp.Entities);
            }
            else
            {
                Exception error = loadOp.Error;
            }
        };
        LoadOperation<WarrantNameDataView> loadOperation = App.cdContext.Load(query, completeProcessing, false);
    }

    private void processWarrantNames(IEnumerable<WarrantNameDataView> entities)
    {
        ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView> NameResult = new ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView>(entities);          
        //we're done
        IsBusy = false;
        CanDo = true;
    }
```

When I set a break on the processWarrantName I can see the NameResult is set to X number of returns. However within the view the datagrid does not get populated with anything?

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do with the bindings to get the gridview to populate? Other areas of the form which are bound to other collections show data so I know I have the data context of the view set correctly. I've tried both Data context as well as Items Source and no return? 
When I set a break on the code the collection is returned as follows so I can see that data is being returned. Any suggestions on what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

With regards to the page datacontext I am setting it in the code behind as follows:

```
        var WarrantDetailViewModel = ((ViewModelLocator)App.Current.Resources["Locator"]).WarrantDetailViewModel;
        this.DataContext = WarrantDetailViewModel;
        this.Resources.Add("vm", WarrantDetailViewModel);
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView> NameResult` a public property of your ViewModel class.  Your view will not be able to bind to something that has a private method scope (or public method scope, or private member scope).

```
//declaration
public ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView> NameResult { get; set }

//in the ViewModel constructor do this
NameResult = new ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView>();

//then replace the original line in your method with:
//EDIT: ObservableCollection has no AddRange.  Either loop through 
//entities and add them to the collection or see OP's answer.
//NameResult.AddRange(entities);
```

If processWarrantNames gets called more than once, you might need to call NameResult.Clear() before  <strike>calling AddRange()</strike>   adding to the collection.

Comment: Thanks Phil That was it. I was so focused on the collection (IENum to OC) that I totally forgot about setting the property to public.

Answer (score 0):

Phil was correct in setting the property to public. One note I'll add is there is no AddRange property in SL or ObservableCollection class that I could find. I was able to assign the entities to the OC using the following code

```
private ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView> warrantNameResult;
    public ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView> WarrantNameResult
    {
        get { return warrantNameResult; }
        set
        {
            warrantNameResult = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(vm => vm.WarrantNameResult);
        }
    }
```

and then within the return method

```
 WarrantNameResult = new ObservableCollection<WarrantNameDataView>(entities);
```

This worked and passed to the UI the collection of data.

Comment: Edited my answer so as not to confuse anyone who comes across it. Glad to hear you got it working.